# Having different versions of the same library in different locations and through different means (apt vs compiling from source)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, libraries

I needed to install opencv version 3.1 for python 3. There was a package called `python-opencv`, but it is version 2.4 and for python 2. So I compiled from the source and installed by `checkinstall`. After that, I realized that I already had libraries starting with `libopencv` which are version 2.4. I guess they were installed as the dependencies of `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` .And when checked my opencv installation from source, I saw that it has also installed some `libopencv` packages such as:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1.0
```

The 2.4 versions were installed through apt, and when I checked the location it was `/usr/lib` not `/usr/local/lib/`.
My question is, does having different versions of the same library installed at different locations cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can. It depends on how your system is configured. If your system finds the older python libraries first in your PATH variable, it will use them.

You can use commands such as update-alternatives to specify which versions of packages you would like to be default on a system. For example, you can use update-alternatives to use an install of java 7 located in /opt as opposed to the openjdk7 installed by default.

You can also place scripts in /etc/profile.d/*.conf to load before any terminal is ran to specify extensions to your PATH variable and also to set other environment variables.

This, or setting environment variables could be used to specify which libraries you would like to use for your program.

Hope this helps! 
Kyle

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure if got it correctly, suppose I imported opencv in python console and it needs libopencv* v3.1 which is installed into /usr/local/lib/ by building from source; it might not check /usr/local/lib/ and may find  libopencv* v2.4 which was installed through apt into /usr/lib/, therefore causing trouble, is it correct? And also, since I installed it by checkinstall, I guess everything will be corrected if I uninstall it(the one builded from source) through apt?

Comment: I apologize if I mis-interpret your comment, I was having trouble with the wording of it. If you manually imported opencv in python, I believe that will override looking for any libraries in the filesystem. It already has it loaded into memory, therefore there is no need to look for it elsewhere. So you are correct, it may cause trouble. Checkinstall should remove all files it placed on the filesystem. You can verify this by using 'dpkg -L <deb pkg filename>' to see all files that were installed from the deb pkg. After you uninstall it, you can check that all those files have been removed.